# How does Apple use App Store image banners?

Tags: ios, appstore

I am about to publish my very first iOS game and was reading the [Apple iTunes Connect guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/iTunesConnect_Guide.pdf) (pages 237 till page 240). I understand that they require a PSD file of dimension 3200x600 pixels. I also understand that this image will be cropped in order to fit the desktop, iPad and iPhone store aras, along with a "minimal view" version.

How, what I don't understand is:

- Do they ever scale the image? I've never seen a high resolution banner in the iPhone Editor's choice images. The iPhone specs are about 640x960 or 640x1136 pixels and the width of the iPhone image area in the guide seems much higher, so that's why I assume the rescale it.
- How do they obtain the "Extreme Skater" 150px300px image on the left, below? Is that simply the title rescaled on a portion of the background? There is no mention of how they do this in the guide.

I imagine that the one on the right is the one obtained from the iPhone area of the editor's choice banner creation guideline, but haven't found any specs on how to obtain the other image.

[image]

How does the Apple measuraments relate to the view I can see here (it is taken from an iPod touch 4th generation with retina display and measured using the rectangle selection on the Mac OS X Preview tool)

[image]

Comment: Have you tried asking them?

Comment: Yes, I did ask this in the iTunes connect forum but no reply since a week. I was wondering if anyone in this site has had a game featured in the Editor's choice. If so I think the person who had would be able to tell me.

Answer (score 1):

The guide defines, as a subset of the "minimum view" area, a "title-safe" region and a "tag area." The title-safe region appears to be what is used to create the small banner that appears in the bottom right of your left-hand screenshot.

I do not believe they ever re-scale the artwork, they just crop it according to their needs. Remember that Apple wants this artwork to display on retina (effectively double-density) screens, so what appears to be a 150x300 pixel image is really a 300x600 pixel image, which fits with their artwork metrics as called out in the guide.

Part of the reason Apple's guidelines for exact pixel dimensions are loose is likely because they want to reserve the right to redesign how they present your artwork within their stores without having to get *new* artwork for all applications. Thus, their guidelines tell you the minimum area you will get (that title safe area), and the rest you have to assume will be dead space (and so you shouldn't put anything super important there).

Comment: Thanks for your clever answer and for the EDIT on my question. Everything helps. I was wondering where you found the 300 x 600 pixels specs in the guide as the Minimum view is 994x400 pixels which correpsonds to about 450x200 which is a big bigger than the 150x300 as shown in the image I just added in the question.

Comment: I did not find specific mention of 150x300 in the guide, I only mentioned it to point that *your* use of 150x300 may be mis-measured (your screenshot was scaled so I can't tell how you obtained it).